# Authentication and Authorization with ASP.NET Core and Service Stack

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, servicestack, identityserver4

I have a ASP.Net Core MVC Web App that users needs to logon to get the id_token from the IdentityServer4 and then that id_token will be passed to webapi implemented in ServiceStack to obtain the authorization code. The subsequent call to the webapi will use the authorization code.

So far what I have read is for the Web App, it should use openid cookie token (UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication).   For the webapi, it should use the bearer token.   My question is how I can pass that http only cookie token from the client side browser as a bearer token in the http header.   As the cookie is http only, it can't be accessed by the Javascript.  Moreover, the ASP.NET Core cookie middleware encrypts the cookie, can that encrypted cookie be decrypted by the ServiceStack webapi (if the cookie is passed to the webapi)?

Am I going in the right direction?   Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example of your scenario here: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html

The authorization code is only used to get access tokens from the identity server, it is not used to authenticate to APIs.

Here is how the flow *should* work:

1. User logs in at Identity Server
2. Your MVC app gets an authorization code and id token

   - The id token tells your MVC app who the user is
3. The authorization code is exchanged for an access token and refresh token with identity server for the API
4. Now the MVC app can make HTTP calls from its backend using the access token
5. Authentication cookie is created and returned to user
6. Front-end submits the authentication cookie with every request to MVC backend, which authenticates every request automatically that hits MVC, then when you want to call the API from there, get it as shown in the docs, and attach it to your requests

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'd like to clarify that the MVC app client (browser) will make the call to the webapi directly, not through the MVC App which I think is what that example is doing and the step 6 (call the API from there) is doing.  

Is it possible to call the webapi directly, not through the MVC app.   Also, the webapi is using ServiceStack without ASP.NET Core, how can it decrypt the ASP.Net Core encrypted cookie.

Comment: The API is called by the MVC app's backend in the example. What you need then is probably using Implicit Grant Flow. And the cookie is meant for your MVC app, there is no need to send it to the API. Your front-end will need to get the access token for the API so it can attach it to AJAX request headers.

Comment: Right, the question is how the " front-end will need to get the access token for the API "?   To get the access-token for the API, the front-end need to pass the identity to the API first, right?  Is the what the id-token for?   But if the id-token got from the MVC App is encrypted in the cookie, how can it be retrieved and pass tot he API.   OR do you mean the access token of the API is got through the MVC App?

Comment: No the id token is not for the API. You get an access token from the identity server, which contains the user info as well. Your API checks the signature of the token and gets the calling user's info from that.

Comment: Since your calls will go from front-end to API directly, this is the scenario that you have: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html#add-a-client-registration-to-identityserver-for-the-javascript-client

Comment: Do you mean the user needs to logon to the API again?   Then user needs to logon to the MVC App and then logon to the API again.  That's not what we want.  We'd like to have the SSO where user logon to the MVC App once only and the token is passed around for the authentication and authorization.

Comment: They don't need to log on again. Try the sample I linked.

Comment: The sample shows it needs to click on Login button and it uses the UserManager.siginRedirect.

function login() {
    mgr.signinRedirect();
}

How does that sigin work?  Does it use the client_id set in the UserManager config to login?

client_id: "js",

Answer (score 0):

I think the point you are missing here is that once the user is logged in, you will get the access token in the response as well when you land back on the client application. If you are using Hybrid Flow, on the client app we configure it as

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies",

    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    Scope = { "api1", "offline_access" },

    GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
    SaveTokens = true
});
```

See the **ResponseType** we ask for code i.e the access code. So you need not to call or login again. Once you want to call your api just get the token like

```
var access_token = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

// call api
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(access_token);

var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
}
```

And if you using Implicit flow, your front end can get the access token using oidc-client library and user.access_token will have it.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong

If it uses Hybrid response type and get the code and id_token from the MVC App, that will be the access token for the MVC App, not the access token for the webapi, right?

Comment: the access token for the MVC app will be what you will be using to access the web api. both are same. Think about it, why would you need access token for the MVC app. Access tokens are for the secured resources like web apis. Try the example samples given with official docs or the one provided by @juunas . I'm sure you won't get any issues.